# bootstrap table styling not working properly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Well to show you the problem I will simply show you an screenshot:

[image]

The Problem is that there is an horizontal scrolling bar, but i want that if the text is longer in one cell, that the text just makes a new line and the cell gets bigger.

Here you can see the markup of that table. I am using the latest bootstrap version

```
            <article class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 pull-right">
                <table class="table table-striped table-condensed">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Room</td>
                            <td>Player</td>
                            <td>Text</td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>

                <?php
                    $chatLog = new ChatLogParser('C:\AtWar\Service\Logs\2014-01-29_chat.log');
                    $logs = $chatLog->parseToObject();
                    foreach($logs AS $log)
                    {
                        echo "<tr><td>".$log[0]."</td><td><strong>".$log[1]."</strong></td><td>".$log[2]."</td></tr>";
                    }
                ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>

            </article>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you have `white-space: nowrap` on the cells. If so change\override it to `white-space: normal`